# Render ListBox item as a simple rectangle (DataTemplate not working) (Ignore: problem caused elsewhere)

Tags: wpf, listbox, wpf-controls, binding, datatemplate

I have a collection of items in an ObservableCollection, and I would like to display each item as a simple rectangle.

I have created a ListBox and bound my collection to it, and it displays a list of strings (ToString() of my items) as expected.
However when I come to change the data template and orientation it no longer displays anything.

Setting ItemsPanel or ItemTemplate both break the listbox, can anyone see an error in my code?

```
    <ListBox Height="100" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="99,151,0,0" Name="listBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=indicators, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="rectangle1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" 
                    Fill="#FF009600" Width="10" />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I found the problem it was in my code behind, test code left over that stopped the listbox updating.
It is now displaying the rectangles, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem lies with the presentation of the elements. Since without the ItemTemplate you saw all the items in the ListBox, I'm sure that they're still there, only you can't see them, most probably because one of the Rectangle's properties is not set properly. For example have you tried giving them a Height too?

Comment: Hi Tenshiko, thanks for your reply. I have tried specifying the rectangles size explicitly but it makes no difference.                         
<Rectangle Name="rectangle1"  RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2" 
Fill="#FF009600" Width="10" Height="10" />

Comment: (Also, the items dissappeared as soon as I tried to change the orientation by setting the ItemsPanel, though remain elusive if I remove this section. Is this normal? (ListBox being unable to display text strings in a horizontal list?)